# How to convert LINQ Method syntax to LINQ Query syntax

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How do I convert the below LINQ Method syntax to LINQ Query syntax? Is there a tool that can help do this? I know LINQPAD can convert from Query syntax to Method syntax but not vice-versa. The reason I want to convert it to query syntax is to do some projection to a model so that I can select few columns from the all the tables mentioned in the LINQ query.

```
var queryResult = CurrentContext.Set<AM_Response_T>().Include(t => t.AM_Master_T)
        .Include(t => t.AM_Supporting_Evidences_T)
        .Include("AM_Supporting_Evidences_T.Ticket_Repository_T")
        .Include(t => t.AM_Response_Validation_T)
        .Include("AM_Response_Validation_T.Amazon_Users_T")
        .Include("AM_Response_Validation_T.Amazon_Users_T1")
        .Include("AM_Response_Validation_T.AM_Validator_Type_T")
        .Include(t => t.Catalog_Type_T)
        .Include(t => t.Skills_T)
        .Include("Skills_T.Record_Status_T")
        .Include("Skills_T.BE_PS_Skill_Map_T")
        .Include("Skills_T.BE_PS_Skill_Map_T.Skills_T1")
        .Include("Skills_T.BE_PS_Skill_Map_T.Skills_T1.Record_Status_T")
        .Include("Skills_T.BE_PS_Skill_Map_T.Skills_T1.BE_PS_Skill_Map_T")
        .Include("Skills_T.BE_PS_Skill_Map_T.Skills_T1.KE_PS_Skill_Map_T")
        .Include("Skills_T.KE_PS_Skill_Map_T")
        .Include("Skills_T.KE_PS_Skill_Map_T.Skills_T1")
        .Include("Skills_T.KE_PS_Skill_Map_T.Skills_T1.Record_Status_T")
        .Include("Skills_T.KE_PS_Skill_Map_T.Skills_T1.BE_PS_Skill_Map_T")
        .Include("Skills_T.KE_PS_Skill_Map_T.Skills_T1.KE_PS_Skill_Map_T")
        .Include(t => t.Skill_Levels_T)
        .Include(t => t.Skills_T.Skill_Levels_T)
        .Include(t => t.Questions_T)
        .Include(t => t.Questions_T.Question_Type_T)
        .Include(t => t.AM_Master_T.AM_Master_Member_Map_T)
        .Include(t => t.AM_Master_T.AM_Master_SPR_Map_T)
        .Include(t => t.AM_Master_T.AM_Master_FSPR_Map_T)
        .Include(t => t.AM_Master_T.AM_Master_FRP_Map_T)
        .Include(t => t.AM_Master_T.AM_Master_Org_Function_Map_T)
        .Include(t => t.AM_Master_T.AM_Master_RRP_Map_T)
        .Include(t => t.AM_Master_T.AM_Master_Skills_Map_T)
        .Include(t => t.AM_Master_T.AM_Master_FCM_Position_T)
        .Include("AM_Master_T.AM_Master_FCM_Position_T.FCM_Position_T")
        .Include(t => t.Amazon_Users_T)
        .Include(t => t.Amazon_Users_T1)
        .Include(t => t.AM_Response_Activity_T);
```

Comment: Resharper can switch back and forth, they have a trial where you can test if it works for your scenario before you buy it. But it's worth buying for everyone who works with C#.

Comment: There's no actual query in the code you've posted - so there's nothing you can convert.

Comment: @Enigmativity do you mean SQL query?

Comment: @nvoigt can you post/point to me the feature of Resharper which i can try?

Comment: I don't know what it's called. R# has so many features, just try it yourself. Install it and wait for the bubble to pop up next to your LinQ.

Comment: @KashifKhan - You haven't posted any C# LINQ query to convert. It's just a bunch of `.Include` statements. They aren't LINQ as such.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use query syntax for this, Method syntax will work just fine. You can use .Select() and .ToList() on there and project to a model:

```
List<ModelYouWantToProjectTo> queryResult = CurrentContext.Set<AM_Response_T>()
    .Include(t => t.AM_Master_T)
    .Include(t => t.AM_Supporting_Evidences_T)
    // Skipped a few
    .Include(t => t.AM_Response_Activity_T)
    .Select(t => new ModelYouWantToProjectTo
        {
            ModelProperty = t.Property,
            // Etc...
        })
     .ToList();
```

As far as I'm aware there's no equivalent of .Include() for query syntax. You could mix the two syntaxes, but I find that doesn't read as clearly.

Comment: On a related note, in a comment because it doesn't really answer your question the .Includes will only affect parts of the model that are projections of entire entities. If you pick and choose properties then the includes are ignored.